# "Please wait, loading..." text during Page_Load on asp.net page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Inside my Page_Load (on Default.aspx) I call a method, which in the end shows some images & text on the page. This takes >30 seconds to load, since it get's these things from various external APIs.
So I thought it would be nice to have a "Please wait, loading application..."-text during that time.

After consulting Google, I guess that using Ajax/jQuery would be the right thing for this.
But I have no clue, how to really achieve that? Or would you guys suggest something totally different?

Of course I found some hints, but they weren't really helpful, since they only started on a button press or similar.

I appreciate any help :-)

Comment: put some relevant code here

Comment: What code would you suggest @SmitPatel

Comment: You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific lines and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since I don't know where to start, I have no code to show.
Everything I could provide would currently be one line with a method call in Page_Load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is the way to go. The `Page_Load` event is called in the process of rendering a page to be send to the client. If that doesn't finish, nothing is sent to the client. So you first have to send something to the client and you can proceed from there.

You want a mechanism somewhat like this I think:

- Generate an ASP.NET page as you do now. Remove all the code from the `Page_Load` that can be moved somewhere else. Show a wait cursor on that page;
- Create a [web service method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ef803zd(v=vs.90).aspx) to be able to get the long-taking stuff.
- Call the web service method and load the retrieved results after it is done.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Ah okay! A web service method! I assumed that I can just do a normal call of an _usual_ method. I'll take a look at that right now. Never worked with Ajax, so this is completely new for me.

Comment: With a web method, you expose some information to the outside. You can't just call any method from your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patrick Hofman, I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted.
For a code sample, I used http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-web-service-using-jque/

If anyone's interested in the code, here you go. Since it's not that much, I'm going to post the full information.

This starts the page, shows a loading text and after 5 seconds, the text switches to the result from the web service method (in the same project).

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SuperWebSvc.asmx/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var names = response.d;
                    // do here, whatever you want to do, after the web service method returned its stuff
                    $('#Content').html(names); // replaces the content of the div with id "content" (only for demo purposes, to keep it simple)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d); // show an alert box, if something goes wrong
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <form id="frm" method="post">
        <div id="Content">
            Please wait, fetching data...
        </div>    
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Web service (SuperWebSvc.asmx)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{       
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SuperWebSvc : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {    
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetData()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> name = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            name.Add("1", "Luke Skywalker");
            name.Add("2", "Han Solo");
            string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(name);
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // wait for 5 seconds, this is just for demo purposes
            return myJsonString;
        }
    }
}
```